# Most efficient way to update an object property within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wondering what is the most efficient way to update an object property that is stored in an array with 10k+ items.

For example if I have an array that holds objects like this {name:"", price:"")

I want to replace or more like update the price values if the array contains that element already.

Check if Array contains object with name = x, if so replace the price with the newest price.

I dont want to have duplicate elements in that array so its not getting to big, i figured I should update it if a property value already exists in it.

So far I have tried several ways like with using indexOf, splice, or just for loops. I am wondering what is the best way performance wise to deal with big arrays.

```js
let array = [
{name:"abc", price: 24},
{name:"cde", price: 25},
{name:"fgh", price: 22},
{name:"gfds", price: 21},
]

function addToArray(elem){
  //check if array contains elem by checking for name property value
  if(array.filter(el => el.name === elem.name).length > 0){
    //update the array element that has the name of the passed elem
  }
}
```

Comment: I mean, fundamentally, a simple loop, but the question is quite vague and open-ended. Perhaps if you could give us an example of a few array elements and the changes you want to make to them.

Comment: i thought I gave the element structure already but I edited initial post, does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've said your starting point is an array, but the most efficient way to do this is with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), not an array, where the key is the name and the value is either the price or an object containing the price (depending on whether you need other information).

### With an Unsorted Array

But if you're doing this with an array, **unless** we can build / maintain the array in sorted order (see "With a Sorted Array" below), there's nothing more efficient than just looping through it looking for a previous element with the given `name`. `filter` isn't the right tool for that (you don't need the array it creates). You'd either write your own loop:

```
let element;
for (let index = 0, length = array.length; index < length; ++index) {
    const thisElement = array[index];
    if (thisElement.name === name) {
        // Already have one
        element = thisElement;
        break;
    }
}
if (element) {
    element.price += price;
} else {
    array.push({name, price});
}
```

With some JavaScript engines, you might get just that *teensy* bit more speed if you declared `index`, `length`, and `thisElement` before the loop:

```
let element, index, length, thisElement;
for (index = 0, length = array.length; index < length; ++index) {
    thisElement = array[index];
    // ...
```

but with others it could be the opposite. (It's not likely to be a big difference either way.)

Or use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const element = array.find(e => e.name === name);
if (element) {
    element.price += price;
} else {
    array.push({name, price});
}
```

Either of those provides linear lookup time. But if you were using a `Map`, you'd get sublinear lookup time.

### With a Map

If using an object as the value:

```
const element = map.get(name);
if (element) {
    element.price += price;
} else {
    map.set(name, {name, price});
}
```

Or if using the price as the value:

```
const currentPrice = map.get(name) ?? 0; // If not found, `get` returns undefined; convert it to 0
map.set(currentPrice + price);
```

### With a Sorted Array

If we can build / maintain the array in sorted order (you've said you can't, but maybe others finding this later can), we can do better than linear lookup by using a binary search (at the cost of *slightly* more overhead when inserting a new element, because all the ones after the insertion point have to be moved). It's more code, but if the search time is the main issue, it cuts search time.

```
const upsert = (array, name, price) => {
    let left = 0;
    let right = array.length;
    while (left < right) {
        let guess = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
        let element = array[guess];
        if (element.name === name) {
            // Found! Update it
            element.price += price;
            return;
        }
        if (element.name < name) {
            left = guess + 1;
        } else {
            right = guess - 1;
        }
    }
    // Not found, insert it
    array.splice(left, 0, {name, price});
};
```

Comment: thank you for your input. Unfortunatly I have to go with an array as it is part of a 3rd party module implementation and I can not change it.

Comment: @BitQueen - Actually, I made an assumption I shouldn't have made: Can we sort the array / build the array in sorted order? If so, we can do a binary search, which would offer sublinear lookup times.

Comment: the order has to remain the same. It is used for a queue that processes items the way they ve been added to the array.

Answer (score 1):

For ONE name, use find:

```js
let array = [
  {name:"abc",  price: 24},
  {name:"cde",  price: 25},
  {name:"fgh",  price: 22},
  {name:"gfds", price: 21},
]

const elem = array.find(({name}) => name==='fgh');
if (elem) elem.price = "40";
console.log(array);
```